# Empty dropdown value: expected options:selected to have text '', but the text was ''

Tags: cypress

I have a dropdown list giving the list of months, but when we first display this page, the dropdown value is empty.
I would like to verify that the initial value is empty before clicking on it and selecting a month.

I tried this:
`cy.get('#yyyy').find('options:selected').should('have.text', '')`
But I get the following error:
`expected options:selected to have text '', but the text was ''`

Do you have any idea for this use case?

Thank you very much

````
<select required="required" aria-required="true" class="custom-select" autocomplete="xxx" id="yyyy">
   <option value="01">January</option>
   <option value="02">February</option>
   <option value="03">March</option>
   <option value="04">April</option>
   <option value="05">May</option>
   <option value="06">June</option>
   <option value="07">July</option>
   <option value="08">August</option>
   <option value="09">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
</select>```
````

Answer (score 4):

The property to check for `<select>` is `value` not `text`.

`.should('have.text')` is only for text between the tags, like `<span>My text here</span>`.

Internally the `<select>` element stores the selection in the `value` property.

If you remove the assertion `.should('have.text', '')` it fails because none of your `<option>` have a `selected` attribute.

```js
cy.get('select').find('option:selected')
```

> **AssertionError**
> Expected to find element: `options:selected`, but never found it.

---

**Testing the correct way**

This passes:

```js
cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', '01')
```

Thats because even though you never selected anything, the `<select>` element has a ***default value*** of the first option.

If you select the 2nd option, the value changes to '02'

```js
cy.get('select')
  .select('February')
  .should('have.value', '02')
```

---

**How to get an empty selection**

Most websites use a placholder when they want an empty default value.

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
  <option value="01">January</option>
  <option value="02">February</option>
  <option value="03">March</option>
  ...
```

Then your test for empty default will be

```js
cy.get('select')
  .should('have.value', '')
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use selector `option:selected` instead of `options:selected` to get the selected element here.

And also just a heads up : with the html you had shared for select element you would still get below error., as it doesn't have an empty text selected by default.

> expected  to have text '', but the text was January

But yeah, assuming your select element has empty option selected you should be able to verify using below command :

```js
cy.get('#yyyy').find('option:selected').should('have.text', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `.should('not.have.text')` or `.should('not.have.value')` and let me know about the result.

Comment: Hello!
`.should('not.have.text')` results in `expected options:selected not to have text undefined` response
and
`.should('not.have.value')` results in `.should('not.have.value')` response as well, this is trange!