# How to check the text of the current state of a select component in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have a select box that originally has no value selected. The box shows as empty, and I would like a cypress test to check that there is no currently selected option, basically check that the select box displays no value.

How can I do that? I tried something like this:

```
cy.get('#filter-dropdown').should('have.text', '')
```

But this doesn't work because the text that it checks is a concatenation of all of the options together.
[image: Select Box is empty]

This is the HTML:

```
<select data-v-1="" id="filter-dropdown" 
    <option data-v-11d8b3dc="" value="a23"> Add Test </option>
    <option data-v-11d8b3dc="" value="532"> Algo</option>
    <option data-v-11d8b3dc="" value="732"> Another</option>
</select>
```

Edit: this is the same question I have, but the answer does not resolve the issue, probably why the answer was not accepted...
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66010066/empty-dropdown-value-expected-optionsselected-to-have-text-but-the-text-wa)

Comment: Can you add the HTML for the drop-down with no value selected.

Comment: And a copy of the HTML when a value is selected.

Comment: When you select any value, can you add the HTML for that, you can use dummy data.

Comment: I have no problem with that, but after selecting, the HTML looks exactly the same

Comment: Can you do this before and after selecting `cy.get('#filter-dropdown').invoke('val').then((val) => {cy.log(val)})`. And tell me the log statements for both.

Comment: So before selecting, the value is null. Is there a way to fail the test in the `then` clause if the value is NOT null? And after selecting, the value logged in the value associated with the `option` selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply an assertion like this:

```js
cy.get('#filter-dropdown')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((val) => {
    expect(val).to.be.null
  })
```